# Make HNQ alt-text consistent

Tags: feature-request, design, hot-questions

Rolling over an SE site icon on the HNQ sidebar shows you the full name of that site (click for larger image):

[image: Sidebar icon alt text]

While on the full HNQ list, rolling over the site icon gives

> view this question on or.stackexchange.com

[image: Main icon alt text]

I don't believe "view this question on [...]" is useful. Rather, removing the link from the icon (like on the sidebar) and giving the full name of the site would be both more consistent and make the list easier to use.